# How to make precise how many numbers have a small factor and how many numbers have a factor near their root?

Tags: factoring, integers

I am reading this article:

https://www.ams.org/notices/199612/pomerance.pdf

The author mentions that trying to factor a number finding two squares such that its difference is the number is worse than trial division because most numbers have a small factor but only a fraction of them have a divisor near their root.

I am wondering how one can make this statement more precise.

Comment: The theory of smooth numbers is useful for the number of numbers with a small factor. I am not sure how to estimate the number of numbers with a factor "near" the square root.